# Using C# to update a Confluence page I keep getting 405 ERROR

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to update a Confluence page.
I have been able to use this on Confluence **localhost**, but when I tried it on the production server I got this error:

```
StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 21:29:44 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.15
  Server: (CentOS)
  Content-Length: 342
  Allow: GET
  Allow: HEAD
  Allow: POST
  Allow: OPTIONS
  Allow: TRACE
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
}
```

This is my code. Any idea what would be causing this issue?

```
string json = "{\"version\":{\"number\":4},\"title\":\"Bloomberg Test\",\"type\":\"page\",\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"Hello World\",\"representation\": \"storage\"}}}";      
string userpass = username+":"+password;
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userpass));
string encval = "Basic " + encoded;
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", encval);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
var resp = client.PutAsync(@"/rest/api/content/"+pageid, content);
```

Answer (score 1):

`405` means that the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT ...) is not allowed.

I don't know the details of Confluence, but try using a `POST` request

```
var resp = client.PostAsync(@"/rest/api/content/"+pageid, content);
```

Comment: Problem is: as per Confluence's documentation: [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/)
Updates are done using PUT requests, and creation of new content is done using POST.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing an HTTP Put via `client.PutAsync()`. This is probably allowed locally, but on the server it's not. The response even includes the allowed http methods:

Allow: GET
  Allow: HEAD
  Allow: POST
  Allow: OPTIONS
  Allow: TRACE

So if the suggested `PostAsync()` is not supported by Confluence, adjust the server and allow the `PUT` method as well.

Comment: RESOLVED! Thank you all for the responses.
It was something silly. I replaced:
`client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);`
With:
`var resp = client.PutAsync(baseurl+"/rest/api/content/"+pageid, content);`

My guess, the BaseAddress is doing something add like adding a slash at the end or something.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
var resp = client.PutAsync(@"/rest/api/content/"+pageid, content);
```

With:

```
var resp = client.PutAsync(baseurl+"/rest/api/content/"+pageid, content);
```

My guess, the BaseAddress is doing something odd like adding a slash at the end or something.

It works now!